# Better way to join tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Good morning,

I have inherited a database with no foreign key relations and the project is such that i have to ignore this major issue and work around it. Obviously this eliminates some of the cooler features of Entity Framework providing me related entities automatically.

So i have been forced to do something like this:

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
    Entities.Info record = db.Infoes.Where(x => x.UserId == authInfo.User.Id).FirstOrDefault();

    //Get all the accounts for the user
    List<Entities.AcctSummary> accounts = db.AcctSummaries.Where(x => x.InfoId == record.Id).ToList();

    //Loop through each account
    foreach (Entities.AcctSummary account in accounts)
    {
        //pull records for account
        List<Entities.Records> records= db.Records.Where(x => x.AcctSummaryId == account.Id).ToList();
    }
}
```

If there a better way to join the "record" and "accounts" Entities, or perhaps a more efficient way for getting "records" in a single query?

TIA

Comment: *Obviously this eliminates some of the cooler features of Entity Framework providing me related entities automatically* Not so obviously, but you can create EF model associations such as *if the FK relations exist in the database*. As far as you configure the cascade delete off and do not use automatic migrations, you could still use the cooler EF features :)

Comment: db.AcctSummaries.Where(x => x.InfoId == record.Id) <- this looks exactly like a FK relationship. why don't you specify InfoId as an FK? if you can't add a navigation property to your object, I do believe the only way is through a manual join, like David suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for the `.Join()` extension method?  As an example, joining `Infoes` and `Accounts` might look like this:

```
var accounts = db.Infoes.Join(db.Accounts,
                              i => i.Id,
                              a => a.InfoId,
                              (info, account) => new { info, account });
```

This would result in `accounts` being an enumeration of an anonymous type with two properties, one being the `Info` record and the other being the `Account` record.  The collection would be the full superset of the joined records.

You can of course return something other than `new { info, account }`, it works just like anything you'd put into a `.Select()` clause.  Whatever you select from these joined tables would be what you have an enumeration of in `accounts`.  You can further join more tables by changing `.Join()` extensions, returning whatever you want from each.

Comment: Is there some what to get this to output as a List<>?

Comment: @Nugs: When you have the expression you want and want to materialize all of the resulting records, you can add a .ToList() to the end.  It's chainable like any other of these extension methods.  Ideally any querying you do can be done before materializing the results, that way you're not requesting more than you need from the database.

Comment: does this need to be an enumeration of an anonymous type. Can i not set this directly into the Entity Entities.Info?

Comment: @Nugs: Oh, of course.  You can select anything you like in that clause.  I only used an anonymous type as a convenient container for both of the types being joined.  But you could just as easily do something like:  (info, account) => account